# How to reorder in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using this code:

```
z <- data.frame(Ins = factor(c("d", "c",    "a",    "e",  "f",  "b")),
            percent = c(2.48,   4.55,   15.16,  16.47,  21.17,  40.17))

ggplot(data=z, aes(x=Ins, y=percent)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_bar(colour="NA", fill="slateblue3", stat="identity") + 
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Year") + ylab ("Procent (%)") +
  ggtitle("People using computers 
       - 2014 -") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, colour='black'))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white'))
```

When I run the plot, R reorders the values as: a, b, c, d, e, f and not the order I gave: d, c, a, e, f, b, which corresponds to increasing order: from 2.48 to 40.17. 
What can I do to keep the order I want? 
10x

Comment: Change the levels of `z$Ins`: `Ins = factor(c("d", "c",  "a", "e",  "f",  "b"), levels = c("d", "c", "a", "e",  "f",  "b"))`.

Comment: Or add `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(z$Ins))`

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was "how to reorder", I think the answer is

```
z$Ins <- reorder( z$Ins, z$percent )
```

which actually reorders the factor and thus, the data.frame (not just the graphical presentation), and does so in a flexible manner (as opposed to from re-assigning the levels explictly).